# Passing data from model to Layout

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have two radio buttons and i wanted to go to different location as they are selected which i have accomplished.

```
$('input[type="radio"]').change(function () {
            var se = $(this).val();
            if (se.length > 0 && se == "cid") {
                window.location.href = "@Url.Action("index", "demo")";

            }
            else {
                window.location.href = "@Url.Action("index", "demo1")";
                 }
        });
```

But radio button is not retaining its selected property after page load.Radio button is coded inside layout view. And i have created a model class for retaining the value of selected button type but when i am passing that model to layout view, there is an exception of type "null reference".

I just want to retain the selection of radio button

Subham

NathCorp, India

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your request i have updated the answer:

Please add the follwing parameter to Index action method in both Demo1 and Demo2 controller as you required,

```
public ActionResult Index(string se, string searchText)
{
     //.....
}
```

Please add "id" attribute for text box and button as well.

```
<form action="/" method="get">
    <p style="color: white;" id="searchbarAnimate">
        <b>SEARCH:</b>
        <input id="txtSearch" type="text" name="searchby" placeholder="Enter Keyword" />
        <input id="btnSearch" type="button" value="search" />
    </p>
</form>
<div>
    <div>
        <input name="se" type="radio" value="cid" />
        CID
    </div>
    <div>
        <input name="se" type="radio" value="others" />
        Others
    </div>
</div>


 function getQueryStringValue(key) {
     return decodeURIComponent(window.location.search.replace(new RegExp("^(?:.*[&\\?]" + encodeURIComponent(key).replace(/[\.\+\*]/g, "\\$&") + "(?:\\=([^&]*))?)?.*$", "i"), "$1"));
 }

 $(document).ready(function() {
     var seQS = getQueryStringValue("se");
     if (seQS && seQS.length) {
         $('input[name="se"][value="' + seQS + '"]').prop('checked', true);
     }

     var searchTextQS = decodeURIComponent(getQueryStringValue("searchText") || '');
     if (searchTextQS && searchTextQS.length) {
         $('#txtSearch').val(searchTextQS);
     }

     function serachWords() {
         var se = $('input[name="se"][type="radio"]:checked').val();
         var searchText = $('#txtSearch').val();

         if (se.length > 0 && se == "cid") {
             window.location.href = '@Url.Action("index", "demo")?se=' + se + '&searchText=' + encodeURIComponent(searchText);
         } else {
             window.location.href = '@Url.Action("index", "demo1")?se=' + se + '&searchText=' + encodeURIComponent(searchText);
         }
     }

     $('input[name="se"][type="radio"]').change(function() {
         serachWords();
     });

     $('#btnSearch').click(function() {
         serachWords();
     });
 });
```

Note: name="se" attribute is mandatory, if any other radio button exists in page.

Please let me know in case of any issues / concerns.

Comment: @subham : WC :). Please accept the answer. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: But there is one more issue.
I have a search bar where i will enter keywords to search, both the textbox and submit buttons are inside a form. But i want that when i search for any word then it will take me to different controller based on radio button.  

http://hawaiinairlines.azurewebsites.net/

Please check the link.
I just want to directs my application to different controllers according to keyword as well as selected radio button

Comment: @subham : can you please update you question for this scenario with an example. So that i can update the answer accordingly...

Comment: @subham : i have updated the answer, Please let me know in case of any issues / concerns.

Comment: Sir, i don't just want to check for keyword. I want to pass the keyword to controllers method and use it there.

Comment: @subham : I have update the answer, Please let me know in case of any issues / concerns

Comment: @subham : Can you please change the type from "submit" to "button", If we are going to redirect the page using jQuery.

Comment: Wow sir, You are amazing.
But still there is an issue.. When i am selecting radio button with value=pid , it automatically changes to cid.

Comment: @subham : http://hawaiinairlines.azurewebsites.net/ website not working. Can you please host it so that i can check it.. Meanwhile please check the value of radio button.

Comment: @subham : Else can you please update your question with exact HTML generated, By right click in browser "View Page Source" for radio button and search form alone...

Comment: @subham : I have update the answer (var se = $('input[name="se"][type="radio"]:checked').val();), Please let me know in case of any issues / concerns

Comment: Thank you sir for helping me to solve this difficult problem from my perception. Really you are amazing. Thank you. Hope to connected to you.